# Is a child allowed to circumcise his father?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, brit-milah, kibbud-av-veim-honoring

Assume that the father is a Gentile who married a Jewish woman. The child, who is Jewish, obviously, becomes a *mohel*.

Years, later, the father decides to convert, so he needs a *brit*. Is the son allowed to the brit on his father, or is this in conflict with any halacha that states that a child is not allowed to physically "injure" his father?

Comment: Once the father converts he cuts off all ties to his previous biological relations. Halachically, he’s not the son’s father. Msh has the right idea of expanding the question to a Jewish father who happened to not have a bris.

Comment: @DonielF That's an interesting point. Based on that, there is no *kibud av* , then?

Comment: Given the various Rabbinic institutions regarding this concept, I’m not going to say no, but there probably isn’t Biblically.

Answer (score 7):

You can ask the same question about a Jewish-from-birth father who happened never to have been circumcised. *Minchas Chinuch* 48 rules that the sin of injuring one's parent does not apply if one does it with the parent's permission. *Shulchan Aruch* [*YD* 241:3](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x6696) seems to disagree, but *Rama* clarifies that *SA* is strict only if no one else is available to do what the father needs done. The case of a convert father that you described would seem to be included by rabbinical decree (*SA* :9, q.v.).

So in short it would seem another circumciser would be preferred according to *SA* but that it is permitted if another circumciser isn't available; and *Minchas Chinuch* permits it anyway.

Comment: I liked your answer before you edited. However, M.C. and SA are addressing the basic issue of wounding a parent, but there's no consideration there for when there is a mitzvah to be fulfilled; which seems to have relevant _nafka minos_.

Comment: @shm better now?

Comment: sorry I hit enter before fully having a formulated thought. I need to look at it inside.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think the rabbinic injunction of a convert not injuring his parent (so he shouldn't say he came from a more holy place to a less holy one) would apply to the mitzvah deoraisa of mila. Even lichatchila.

Comment: Although the flipside of that is the only allowance tip circumcise him (unless he is an ismealite) would be to convert him, at which point there is a more real relationship as the son in retrospect counts towards the father's pru urvu.